# Customize error message when compiling PDF

Tags: r, pdf, error-handling, knitr, sweave

Given the following R knitr document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<data>>=
opts_chunk$set(comment = NA)  # omits "##" at beginning of error message
x <- data.frame(x1 = 1:10)
y <- data.frame()
@ 

<<output_x>>=
if (nrow(x) == 0) stop("x is an empty data frame.") else summary(x)
@

<<output_y>>=
if (nrow(y) == 0) stop("y is an empty data frame.") else summary(y)
@

\end{document}
```

As expected, the last chunk returns an error with the custom message. The compiled PDF looks a little different:

```
Error: y is an empty data frame.
```

I want this text to just be

```
y is an empty data frame.
```

Without the `Error:` part or the red color. Can I achieve this? How?

**Edit:** I was able to make it in the mock data through the following workaround:

```
<<output_y>>=
if (nrow(y) == 0) cat("y is an empty data frame.") else summary(y)
@
```

However, that doesn't work with my real data, because I need the function to be stopped at that point.

Comment: In regards to your edit, perhaps a `break` statement to stop the function?

Comment: @RichardScriven, I'm not sure I'm using it right, but inserting `break` at the end of the `if` statement just gives me another error: `no loop for break/next, jumping to top level`. The function is not inside of a loop, it's a simple function to create some subsets and make some calculations to create a latex table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I do not understand why an error should not be called `Error`, you are free to customize the output hook `error` to remove `Error:` from the message:

```
library(knitr)
knit_hooks$set(error = function(x, options) {
  knitr:::escape_latex(sub('^Error: ', '', x))
})
```

Comment: Nothing like the man himself to solve the issue. Thanks! BTW, the reason for the customization is that in my real case the error is caused by the function trying to do computations on an eventually empty object, in which case I want my client to just get a nice "this table is empty" message instead of "Error" in his PDF report.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. `options("show.error.messages" = FALSE)` turns off error messages, so you could temporarily employ that once the `if` statement is entered and use `on.exit` to reset it.

This way, `stop` stops the function, `Error:` is avoided, and the desired message is printed in red.

```
> f <- function(x) {
      if(x > 5) {
          g <- getOption("show.error.messages")
          options(show.error.messages = FALSE)
          on.exit(options(show.error.messages = g))
          message("x is greater than 5.")
          stop()
      }
      x
  }
> f(2)
# [1] 2
> f(7)
# x is greater than 5.
```

Note:  I'm not exactly sure how safe this is and I'm not a big supporter of changing `options` settings inside functions.

Comment: Interesting: the R output is suppressing the error messages (as expected), but they still show up in the compiled PDF. I'll take another look at http://yihui.name/knitr/options and see if I can find anything.