# How do I customize an error message sent to the console?

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm using `knitr` to produce a report for each department of an organization. Each report contains a few tables, but for some departments, one or more of those tables lack data to display. Therefore, when using R chunks within an `Rmd` document (and specifying `results='as-is'`) to evaluate my table creation functions (e.g., `print.xtable()` or `htmlTable()` from the `gMisc` package), I get an unpleasant looking error message printed to my output document that (in true R fashion) indicates with great specificity what went wrong. Of course, the high level message is "there was no input to this function".

How can I, then, customize what is printed to the console, and therefore what gets printed to my output document when `knitr` evaluates my results `'as-is'`?

I'm aware that I can wrap my table creation function with `try(function, silent = TRUE)` to banish the error message altogether, but I'd prefer a meaningful message (like "You idiots forgot to send in your data!" or, more diplomatically, "No data to present.") rather than the lack thereof.

Thanks.

Comment: This example shows a custom error message from a try catch block. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128455/r-try-catch-block

Answer (score 0):

I missed this link the first time around when posting this question, but the following thread poses a very similar question, and was answered by @Yihui:

[Customize error message when compiling PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493026/customize-error-message-when-compiling-pdf?rq=1)